# Webpack: postcss-loader is ignoring config file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, postcss, autoprefixer, postcss-loader

Currently I have the following webpack configuration, which works fine:

```
{
  loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
  options: {
    ident: 'postcss',
    plugins: () => [
      require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: [
          '>1%',
          'last 4 versions',
          'Firefox ESR',
          'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
        ],
        flexbox: 'no-2009',
      }),
    ],
  },
},
```

Since I'm using the postcss configuration in several places, I want to centralize it in a **postcss.config.js** file.

My webpack config becomes :

```
{
  loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
  options: {
    ident: 'postcss',
    config: {
      path: './postcss.config.js'
    },
  },
}
```

My postcss.config.js file is in the same config folder, and looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-flexbugs-fixes': {},
    'autoprefixer': {
      browsers: [
        '>1%',
        'last 4 versions',
        'Firefox ESR',
        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
      ],
      flexbox: 'no-2009',
    }
  }
}
```

Now the build is still working, but it seems that the postcss config is ignored (when I inspect the css, the vendor prefix are no longer there). Am I missing something here ? The postcss documentation is not very helpful...

Comment: Have you tried without path declaration ? If your `postcss.config.js` is in the same directory as webpack config it should detect it by default.

Comment: @Dyo Yes I tried that as well, to no avail.

Comment: You're still declaring `loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader')`, in webpack right ?

Comment: Yes (I just edited my post)

Comment: same problem, and `postcss` github config is useless

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Try These:

First in `webpack`:

```
{
  loader: 'postcss-loader',
  options: {
    config: {
      path: `${__dirname}/postcss.config.js`,
    },
  },
}
```

And then in your `postcss.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  ident: 'postcss',
  syntax: 'postcss-scss', /*install "postcss-scss" for SCSS style */
  map: false, /*its depends on your choice*/
  plugins: {
    'postcss-flexbugs-fixes': {},
    'autoprefixer': {
      browsers: [
        '>1%',
        'last 4 versions',
        'Firefox ESR',
        'not ie < 9',
      ],
      flexbox: 'no-2009',
    }
  }
}
```

This works for me. If have some problems [tell me](https://twitter.com/amerllica)